# Compare values in SQL having dots

Tags: mysql

I'm comparing values from two different database.
In one table the name is stored with dots(i.e A.B C) and in another table the same value is stored as AB C(i.e in second table none of the names contain dots)
In SQL how can I compare the values? Dot can come anywhere in the name.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `replace` function:

```
mysql> select replace("A.B C", ".", "") = "AB C";
+------------------------------------+
| replace("A.B C", ".", "") = "AB C" |
+------------------------------------+
|                                  1 |
+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF((select REPLACE(name,'.','') from #tmpDots) = (select name from #tmpNoDots))
PRINT 'TRUE'
ELSE
PRINT 'FALSE'
```

Replace the dots with the space of the characters that are worrying you using the **Replace()** function in SQL and this should do it. You can also embed this logic in some SQL function or in an SP.

Let me know if more help needed.